# How to reorder elements in a tree panel using treeviewdragdrop plug in?

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, treeview, extjs4.2

I have added the following code in my viewConfig. I have also tried creating another ptype and using the same name for dragGroup and dropGroup.
Any help shall be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

plugins: {
                ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
                appendOnly: true,
                ddGroup: 'sampleDDGroup'
            }

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct. Sharing of code would have helped.

Here's a working sample:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        viewConfig: {
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
                appendOnly: true,
                ddGroup: 'sampleDDGroup'
            }
        },
        root: {
            text: 'Root',
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: 'A',
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: '1',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: '2',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: 'B',
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: '1',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Check this fiddle: [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2721)